# Language Tamil Male give 2 different voices and male or female voices for big story

Tags: jquery, responsivevoice

I Used jquery webspeaker for text to speach.I gave language option as "Tamil Male"

```
$('.speaker-article').webSpeaker({language: "Tamil Male"});
```

sample site url is [here](http://electionstg.dailythanthi.com/News/State/2017/09/21003658/18-MLAs-do-not-prohibit-eligibility.vpf)

It produces both female or male voices for big story.But,we need only one voice.can anyone pls help me to get this

Thanks

Comment: I tried the sample site you have provided and it seems that the plugin is not working. It is returning a `403` not found error for your selected Tamil voice.